# How to remove elements in arrayList by key

Tags: java

```
ArrayList<String> single = new ArrayList<String>();
---------         
System.out.println(single)
```

arrayList recovered

```
[Document{{googContentType=realtime, packetsLost=0, id=ssrc_3841594688_recv, type=ssrc, timestamp=2019-07-11T07:18:43.413Z}}
,Document{{googContentType=realtime, packetsLost=0, id=ssrc_239620516_recv, type=ssrc, timestamp=2019-07-11T07:18:42.955Z}}]
```

the desired result

```
[Document{{ packetsLost=0, timestamp=2019-07-11T07:18:43.413Z}}
,Document{{ packetsLost=0,  timestamp=2019-07-11T07:18:42.955Z}}]
```

Comment: what to you mean by desired result without explaining the problem?

Comment: You are missing the code of your attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: He wants to remove fields in the objects I take it.

Comment: i want to remove some key in my arrayList; i used removedIf but i can't do it

Comment: removeIf (Predicate filter) : Removes all of the elements of this collection that satisfy the given predicate. You should use remove (index) or remove (object).
Just one other thing : try to declare as : List<String> list = new ArrayList<>()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily best practice, but you could do a regex replacement to remove the key-value pairs which you don't want in your final output:

```
List<String> singleOut = single.stream()
    .map(x -> x.replaceAll("(?:googContentType|id|type)=\\S+\\s*", ""))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

singleOut.forEach(System.out::println);
```

This prints:

```
Document{{packetsLost=0, timestamp=2019-07-11T07:18:43.413Z}}
Document{{packetsLost=0, timestamp=2019-07-11T07:18:42.955Z}}
```

The best solution here would be to go back to the tool/code which generated this JSON-esque objects, and reexport containing only the `packetsLost` and `timestamp` keys which you want to appear.

Comment: Thank you for your help